# How to summarize the content by brackets?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to summarize an array like this:[image]

and make a outline with the following style:
[image]
What is the template of this syntax? Moreover, is it possible to put a symbol(or sentence) at any certain place by coordination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that produces an output reminiscent of your drawing. It will only be possible to determine a very good way of doing such things if you provide us with more context, i.e. the code you have tried.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item $\tikzmarknode{1}{N(L^*)=R(L^*)^\perp;}$
 \item $\tikzmarknode{2}{{}^\perp N(L^*)=\overline{R(L)};}$
 \item $\tikzmarknode{3}{{}^\perp  N(L)={}^\perp R(L^*);}$
 \item $\tikzmarknode{4}{{}N(L^*)=\overline{R(L^*)}^{n*};}$%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
    decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=4pt},very thick]
  \path[local bounding box=top] (1.north east)  -- (2.south east);
  \draw[decorate] ([xshift=1ex]top.north east)  -- ([xshift=1ex]top.south east)
   node[midway,right=1ex]{$L$ is densely defined};
  \path[local bounding box=bot] (3.north east)  -- (4.south east);
  \draw[decorate] ([xshift=1ex]bot.north east)  -- ([xshift=1ex]bot.south east)
   node[midway,right=1ex]{$L$ is closed graph};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
\[\text{map}~\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}l@{}}
 \text{function}&\colon \mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{F}\\[1em]
 \text{functional}&\colon C(\mathbb{F})\to\mathbb{F}\\[1em]
 \text{operator}&\colon C(\mathbb{F})\to C(\mathbb{F})
\end{array}\right.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I hadn’t tried it yet. The only method I considered is add it manually by annotation, which is quite awkward. By the way can you add the code for my last question? Thank you very much.